# "自然な流れ" and "サボろう" mean

Tags: meaning, words

In this sentence "自然な流れでサボろうと思ったのにちょっと言い過ぎたかな" ,there are 
two phrases i don't know the meaning  "自然な流れ" and  "サボろう" . "自然な流れ" I think it means "natural flow" but what is " natural flow". Also, "サボろう" I absolutely do not know.help me

Comment: サボろう is just an inflection of サボる, if that helps you get started.

Comment: Without further context, this question could not be answered with authority.

Answer (score -1):

サボる is slang.This means you don't do your duty.
自然な流れ is the way which doesn't make the feeling of strangeness.
So for example, don' do homework is サボる and explain good excuse is 自然な流れでサボる.